# how to display values in dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, json, select

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bl9j.jpg)I am trying to display values in a multi-select dropdown, those values are coming from an API. below I have given JSON format in which data is received from API.

the below data is that the user already selected values, now I am displaying a popup to edit the selected values, before this, I need to show the user that the user is previously selected in the multi-select dropdown.

```
//below is my values coming from API
[
 {id: 1, name: "selected 1"},
 {id: 2, name: "selected 2"}
]
```

// below is my dropdown element

```
               <select id="selected"  name="selected[]"  multiple>
                <option  value="" >  </option>
                </select>
```

Comment: you can do it using dom API. search for how you can access `select` tag and append options into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, I think you can do like this.

```
<select name="selected[]" id="selected" multiple>
  <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
  <?php
    foreach($users as $user) { 
  ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $user['id'] ?>"><?php echo $user['name'] ?></option>
  <?php
    } 
  ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as per my understanding from your question, you would like to show all those values which the user selected before. If I'm right, then we may have 2 solutions. 1) To keep the track at server end(i.e in the database) 2) To keep track at the client side (i.e in cookies on a temporary basis),

Please let me know if I answered your question. If don't then please elaborate your question in more detail with the reference code snippet.

Comment: yes, correct. I want to display previously selected values in the selected state  along with the remaining values in the dropdown.

Comment: i have added a new image. like that i needed.

Comment: Okay perfect. I will recommend you the following jQuery plugins as per your requirements.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Custom-Tags-Input-Select-Box-selectize-js/examples/

https://www.cssscript.com/demo/multiple-select-dropdown/

Comment: You can also use the following as well which is most close to your requirements.

https://www.cssscript.com/demo/multiple-select-dropdown/